# Converting Data in Excel file to JSON and storing it in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, csv

i have a excel file with some data , now i want to take data from this excel file and store it into mongodb same as we store data through making mongoose schema. I dont know anything about this process , i,m totally new . so can someone please suggest me a proper documentation for this or guide me where to start ... and if possible can tell me how this whole process works (**Basic steps**)
Iam using Nodejs express

Answer (score 0):

**Basic steps:**
convert the excel to js object (use npm to install):
https://www.npmjs.com/package/convert-excel-to-json

*.. maybe convert the result object to match mongo schema .. (just js code, change properties etc.)*

save the object to db:
https://www.kompulsa.com/introduction-mongoose-storing-data-mongodb/
(in this example it will be `new Bug(YOUROBJECT)`)